# How exactly does the Navigo pass work?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, paris

I've read all the answers on here about the pass but I want to know much more.  What size does the photo have to be? Can I buy a  pass for my friend and can she stick in the photo when I give her the pass or does it have to be done at a station?  What are the zone choices?  I heard there is 2 parts to the card; do you have to buy some kit separately?  How do you activate it because I read it is valid up to 10 years? What's the current prices?  What 's the difference between this and the Navigo Decouverte?  Finally, are there any passes that cover weekends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in fact, navigo is just the new carte orange.

so for the price, so you have, with the navigo card, three different time length for navigo:

- week (for zone 1-2, (paris only), 19,8€) from monday to sunday
- month (for zone 1-2, (paris only), 65,1€)
- year  (for zone 1-2, (paris only), 679€)

  Note that a Navigo monthly or yearly pass (but not a weekly pass) is valid for the whole Île-de-France region on week-ends and public holidays.

the difference beetween navigo and navigo decouverte is navigo vanilla is personal and you have to go to an ratp office because they took a photo of directly in the chip card. fro vanilla navigo, there are only one part.the vanilla is only for Parisian people.

the navigo decouverte is the two part card more like the old carte orange. easier to get, you can have it without to go to ratp.there are two part. a chip card without identity and and a card where you write your name and put a photo. you need to have cards to travel but it's the chip car the card who need to be recharged.

i think you buy a card for you friend and put photo after.

about the choice for zone, as i said before, the smallest subscription is zone 1 and 2 but the zone 3 is quite near( for exemple you have la defense in zone 3)
you can see all the maps in english there http://www.ratp.fr/plan-interactif/carteidf.php?lang=uk
but if you take a small zone, you can buy a "complement de parcours" and go outside.

NEVERTHELESS there are other subscriptions as paris visite, for exemple.

Comment: If I go to an RATP office do I have to prove I live there?

Comment: How do I activate it?  By using it for the first time or...?  Are the colours of the monthly and weekly pass different?

Comment: So, if I buy the 1-2 zone monthly pass I can travel outside to all zones for free and I can use the metro on weekends?

Comment: if you buy a navigo decouverte, you don"t have to prove your paris residence. for dezonage, yes, you can go for all zone on week end and public holidays with a montly pass. you activate it when you pay the first time. (so you can buy a week tree month before)

Comment: Sorry,  I'm not too clear on the activation process.  Can we fill it anytime or it HAS to be when we buy it?....like say if I buy a week and I don't use it during the week...what happens?  Does it expire and then I have to refill again?

Comment: if you buy a week(a week is from Monday to Sunday, so if buy a week for instance on a Thursday, the week end on the Sunday), at the end of this week, you HAVE TO buy another week regardless use of the pass. you can't buy two week in advance. it why there are some queues on Monday or on the first day of the month. as i said before, if you stay 5 day, there are tourist pass that could be more usable...

Comment: Which part of a pass is valid for 10 years?  Do you happen to know?

Comment: i suppose it is the identity part of navigo but it's only matter to say you have to change some time.